# How to resolve Attribute error in SSH connection using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, serial-port

I am trying below code snippet to run the command using ssh in the background session. But it resulting in "chan = ssh_transport.open_session() Attribute Error:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'"
Any suggestion to resolve this error would be very helpful,Thankyou.

```
def background(self, cmd, working_directory):
            if hasattr(self, "bkg_sessions") is False:
                self.bkg_sessions = {}
    
            ssh_transport = self.paramiko_client.get_transport()
            chan = ssh_transport.open_session()
            chan.invoke_shell()
            if working_directory:
                chan.send(f'cd {working_directory}\n'.encode())
                time.sleep(1)
            chan.send(f'{cmd}\n'.encode())
    
            self.bkg_sessions[chan] = {}
            return chan
```

Comment: According to the error message, it means ssh_transp should be None.Do you create the instance of paramiko_client?And also we can't get to know what this variable is refer to.

Comment: Please add what you have referred with `self.paramiko_client`

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe, self.paramiko_client = None, it is assigned to none

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set the `self.paramiko_client` to `None`. You need to set it to `SSHClient()` in order to make it work.

Example:

```
from paramiko.client import SSHClient

class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.paramiko_client = SSHClient()

    def background(self, cmd, working_directory):
        if hasattr(self, "bkg_sessions") is False:
            self.bkg_sessions = {}

        ssh_transport = self.paramiko_client.get_transport()
        chan = ssh_transport.open_session()
        chan.invoke_shell()
        if working_directory:
            chan.send(f'cd {working_directory}\n'.encode())
            time.sleep(1)
        chan.send(f'{cmd}\n'.encode())

        self.bkg_sessions[chan] = {}
        return chan
```

Comment: still the error is not resolved, resulting in same error chan = ssh_transport.open_session(), 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'

Comment: Please paste the full code to your question.